# Electron JS application open at login after providing admin privilege not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, root-access

In my electron js application, I need to execute a command, that should have administrative privilege. So in the Windows app build configuration, I added a parameter "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator". I built the app successfully and installed it. After enabling this one of my application behavior apps will launch after boot the device. I need admin privilege and the app will launch after restarting the device. How can we enable both behaviors? What configuration change I need to do for this. Could you please provide any hint for this?